не создаётся таблица в бд
В базе данных создаются все таблицы из этих Java классов кроме User, даже таблица user_role создаётся которая находится внутри класса User, расскажите в чём ошибка
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastname;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String bio;
    @Column(length = 3000)
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ERole.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<ERole> roles = new HashSet<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @Transient
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> autorities;
    public User() { }
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}

public enum ERole {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}
@Data
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Post post;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long userId;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", nullable = false)
    private String messege;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
@Data
@Entity
public class ImageModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BYTEA")
    private byte[] imageBytes;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long userId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long postId;
}
@Data
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private  String caption;
    private String location;
    private Integer likes;
    @Column
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    private Set<String> likedUsers = new HashSet<>();
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "post", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
@SpringBootApplication
public class InstazooApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InstazooApplication.class, args);
    }
}

application.properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Sprngbt?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

pom.xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Приведи пример кода для создания таблицы.

В приведенном коде каждый класс это таблица, которая должна создаться в базе данных при запуске кода. У меня в базе данных создаются все таблицы кроме одной

Проблема решилась, таблица создалась. В Postgresql user - служебное слово, и таблица с таким именем не может быть создана.
